# how to make a get-form in flask

Tags: flask

I have a form which is like

```
<form action="{{ url_for('my_form')}}" method="get">

            <h2><td><input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="{{ user_name }}">{{ user_name }}</td></h2><br>

             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
```

And then on flask backend

```
@app.route('/my_form', methods=['GET'])
def my_form():
    print request.form.items()
    user_name = request.form['user_name']
    print "exclusive request"
    print "got user name ", user_name
```

But this doesnt work as the submit query becomes
http://local_host/my_form?user_name=foobar  <--- 400 error

which makes sense.. as the query url is `my_form`
So, the question is how to make a get form in flask?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#incoming-request-data) we use form attribute of request  only with **POST** method or **PUT** in your case as you are using **GET** try *args* parameters:

> form A MultiDict with the parsed form data from POST or PUT requests.
>   Please keep in mind that file uploads will not end up here, but
>   instead in the files attribute.
>
> args A MultiDict with the parsed contents of the query string. (The
>   part in the URL after the question mark).

use this in your backend :

```
@app.route('/my_form', methods=['GET'])
def my_form():
    print request.args.items()
    user_name = request.args['user_name']
    print "exclusive request"
    print "got user name ", user_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You are try to access to POST request parameter but your route accept only GET request. To resolve this just add POST in the method argument of your route decorator.

```
@app.route('/my_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_form():
    print request.args.items()
    user_name = request.form.get('user_name')
    print "exclusive request"
    print "got user name ", user_name
```